# Upgrade sqlite database file

Tags: sqlite, upgrade

I use sqlite database in .net application, and need to upgrade the database version from 3.8.x to 3.8.y. There is no problem with newly createad database which I will create with updated sqlite .dlls, but what about existing files?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have no problem because according to the [offical website](https://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html), sqlite maintains backwards compatibility:

> The SQLite database file format is also stable. All releases of SQLite
>   version 3 can read and write database files created by the very first
>   SQLite 3 release (version 3.0.0) going back to 2004-06-18. This is
>   "backwards compatibility". The developers promise to maintain
>   backwards compatibility of the database file format for all future
>   releases of SQLite 3.

Comment: I had the same problem, and found the answer here:
http://www.dosomethinghere.com/2013/02/20/fixing-the-sqlite-error-the-database-disk-image-is-malformed/
The idea is simply to export to sql and re-import.